# Change display and icon when click on <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know how to change display style and  element class when I click on  element:
and also I'm loading " jquery.min.js version: 2.1.4 " and " bootstrap.min.js "

**Before** click on  element:

```
<ul class"nav navbar-nav" >
<li class="nav-item search">
<!-- this a element -->

            <a class="nav-link search-toggle" id="nav-link-search" href="#" title="Search Posts">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>

              <span class="sr-only">
                Search
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <progress class="nav-progressbar" max="100" title="How much of the page you have seen so far. Hold and drag to change page position." value="0"></progress>
    </nav>
    <div class="search-area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="search-area-input">
          <input placeholder="Search articles" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="search-area-results index">
          <ol class="article-index-list"></ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And **after** click on  element:

```
<nav class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item search">
<!-- this a element -->

            <a class="nav-link search-toggle" href="#" title="Search articles">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" title="Close search"></i>

              <span class="sr-only">
                Search
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <progress class="nav-progressbar" max="100" title="How much of the page you have seen so far. Hold and drag to change page position." value="0"></progress>
    </nav>
    <div class="search-area" style="display: block;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="search-area-input">
          <input placeholder="Search articles" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="search-area-results index">
          <ol class="article-index-list"></ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry.. is there any difference between the two code blocks with the exception of style="display:block" on the search-area class?

Comment: before: style="display:none" and after click on <a> element: style="display:block" @oompahlumpa

Comment: `$('a').on('click',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('.search-area').addClass('something').removeClass('somethingElse'); });`

Comment: what about the <i> element class and title ? @MichaelCoker

Comment: @Artimos  `$('i.fa').addClass('something').removeClass('somethingElse').attr('title','foobar');` or add a more descriptive class to that element and target it that way instead of `i.fa`

Comment: :D yeah... thx @MichaelCoker

Comment: @Artimos np, I'll move this to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var i =$(this);
    i.removeAttr('title');
    i.attr('title','Search articles');
    i.removeAttr('id');
    var j = $('i.fa-search');
    j.removeAttr('class');
    j.attr('class','fa fa-fw fa-times');
    j.attr('title','Close search');
    $('.search-area').css('display',"block");
});
```

if u want to (display:none) again

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var i =$(this);
    i.removeAttr('title');
    i.attr('title','Search Posts');
    i.attr('id','nav-link-search');
    var j = $('i.fa-times');
    j.removeAttr('class');
    j.attr('class','fa fa-fw fa-search');
    j.removeAttr('title');
    $('.search-area').css('display',"none");
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @Artimos Updated code :)
Sry forget to put the closing parenthesis ^^

Comment: I get display none instead of block :|

Comment: @Artimos updated to revert back click event.
none? i don't get it?
u want display none on first click event?

Comment: when I use your code I get this: style="display:none;"

Comment: but when I remove this file all codes work - [master-bcbe.js](https://ijapan.one/ht/master-bcbe.js)

Comment: @Artimos not sure about that file... if i could look more into your code, i might help you out.... the console log is clean ... means you are not getting any error, it must be some other issue.

Comment: I just found this code which works perfectly `$( function() {
              $( "a.search-a" ).on( "click", function() {
                  $( "div.search-area" ).toggleClass( "showw" );
              });
          } );` but I can't write something like this for <i> class ( Replace the class ) - which @oompahlumpa told me :/

Comment: @Artimos check if this works
$( function() { $( "a.search-a" ).on( "click", function() { 
    $( "div.search-area" ).toggleClass( "showw" ); 
        $( "i.fa-times" ).toggleClass( "fa fa-fw fa-times" ); 
        $("i.fa-times").toggleClass("fa fa-fw fa-search");
    }); 
} );

Answer (score 3):

```js
    $(document).on('click', ".search-toggle", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".search-area").show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div><ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item search">
    <!-- this a element -->

    <a class="nav-link search-toggle" id="nav-link-search" href="#" title="Search Posts">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>

      <span class="sr-only">
                Search
              </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<progress class="nav-progressbar" max="100" title="How much of the page you have seen so far. Hold and drag to change page position." value="0"></progress>
</nav>
<div class="search-area" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search-area-input">
      <input placeholder="Search articles" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="search-area-results index">
      <ol class="article-index-list"></ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok this one works... so if I want to get display none again? and change <i> class

Answer (score 2):

The code below will add the display: block to the element "search-area".  This is given you have a clicking element with the class "element".

```
$(".element").click(function(){
  $(".search-area").css( "display", "block" );
});
```

Comment: ok this one works... so if I want to get display none again? and change <i> class

Comment: Do you want to click the same element?  If so I would suggest using `.toggleClass("myCustomClass")` and then create css styling to do the `display: block`.  This way if the element has that class it's block, if not it's none.

Comment: sorry but can you edit your code and also what about <i> class and titles?

Answer (score 2):

To change an element when you click on a link, the general concept is

```js
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
  $('.search-area').addClass('something').removeClass('somethngElse'); // change .search-area
  $('i.fa').addClass('something').removeClass('somethingElse').attr('title','foobar'); // change your i element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class"nav navbar-nav" >
<li class="nav-item search">
<!-- this a element -->

            <a class="nav-link search-toggle" id="nav-link-search" href="#" title="Search Posts">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>

              <span class="sr-only">
                Search
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <progress class="nav-progressbar" max="100" title="How much of the page you have seen so far. Hold and drag to change page position." value="0"></progress>
    </nav>
    <div class="search-area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="search-area-input">
          <input placeholder="Search articles" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="search-area-results index">
          <ol class="article-index-list"></ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
    at Function.e.Index.load (master-bcbe0114.js:7)
    at Object.success (master-bcbe0114.js:90)
    at j (jquery.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3211)
    at x (jquery.js:8264)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8605)

Comment: @Artimos I need to see that myself. Please provide a working demo replicating the problem.

Comment: sorry but I can't do that....but also I'm loading this file too: [master-bcbe.js](https://ijapan.one/ht/master-bcbe.js)